# What is the probability that the man will end in that point?

Tags: probability

A man has a finite empty checklist of pairs of numbers (all squares are empty), a fair (balanced) coin, i.e. if the man tosses his coin then the probability that the coins shows **head** is equal to the probability that the coin shows **tail** that is equal to 0.5, and a pen.

while the man didn't finish the checklist he tosses his coin.

If coin shows **head** then the man moves according to the **first** number in the current pair in the checklist.

If coin shows **tail** then the man moves according to the **second** number in the current pair in the checklist.

The number indicates how many meters the man has to walk.

If the number is **positive** then the man is moving **forward** and if the number is **negative** then the man is moving **backward**.

After the man has finished moving he checks with his pen the current pair and proceeds to the next pair.

If that was the last pair then the man is done with the checklist, i.e. finished it.

Given the checklist, what is the probability that the man will finish on the same point that he started on?

Is there a **general** formula to compute this by using some known distribution?

EDIT:

Each element/item of the checklist is member of $\mathbb{R^2}$ and it can be either positive or negative obviously. Otherwise the question is not interesting and the answer is obvious that the man won't get back to the point he started on.

Comment: this is very hard to follow.  What numbers are written in the checklist?  Maybe all the numbers are positive, in which case he can never get home.  In any case, the contents of the checklist are critical.  (I see that you say the checklist is empty, no numbers at all, but I can't figure out what you mean by that...as later on you refer to the numbers on the list).

Comment: @lulu I didn't say in my question that all the numbers are positive and there is no sense if all the numbers are positive.

Comment: My point was that the numbers on the list are critical and you didn't give us any information about them.  Well, in the first paragraph you said there weren't any, but I assume that was an error.

Comment: @lulu My question is **general**, but not specific. I seek for **formula**. I said this in my question. Please read carefully. I tried to google for this formula, but I didn't find it.

Comment: Voting to close the question as it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @lulu it is clear enough - given some finite collection of pairs of real numbers $A$, choose one number from each pair with equal probability and form a new collection $B$. What is then asked is if there is some general way to compute the probability that the sum of $B$ is 0.
Yes, there is no info about $A$, and that makes the question harder, however that does not make the question less clear.

Comment: @cirpis You are intelligent person indeed. You've got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us denote the checklist as an ordered set of $n$ pairs $C$, and the $i$th pair in $C$ as $(a_i, b_i)$, where $b_i>a_i$ (the ordering of $a$ and $b$ within a pair does not matter).

It is easy to see that essentially every possible path the man can make corresponds to a string of length $n$ consisting of $a$s and $b$s. Since at every step the man chooses either $a$ or $b$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ then every path occurs equally likely with probability $\frac{1}{2^n}$.

So now all that is left is to compute how many of the paths sum to $0$.

Let us change the problem a little bit, and replace each pair with $(0, b_i-a_i)$ and instead of asking whether there is a path summing to $0$, lets ask if there is a path summing to $A = -a_1-a_2 \dots -a_n$ (this is equivalent to the previous problem, since if we added back the $a_i$s we would get a sum of $0$ and the original numbers).

However with this change in pairs, each path is actually simply a subset of the set $S = \{b_1-a_1, b_2-a_2 \dots b_n-a_n\}$ since adding a zero doesnt change anything (at each step the man chooses to either go $b_i-a_i$ miles or not to go).

So we have reduced the problem to the well known [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), that asks whether a subset of a given set of numbers ($S$ in our case) has a sum equal to a given fixed number ($A$ in our case).

The algorithms given in the Wikipedia page can be generalised to also count the numbers of occurences of the sum.

However, what this tells us is that in general, this is a pretty hard problem that doesnt have a polynomial time algorithm. What this means is that there is most likely also no "formula" to calculate the number of zeroes in the general case (if we have no information on the numbers in the checklist).